# Shiny: Is there a way to enable mouse wheel zoom only after click on map in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Is there a way to enable mouse wheel zoom only after first click on map.

I have the following code in which I want to zoom the map only after click on the map. Is there a way to do that in shiny?

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(maps)

ui <- fluidPage(
 leafletOutput("CountryMap", width = 1000, height = 500)
)

server <- function(input, output){
   Country = map("world", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE, regions="USA", exact=TRUE)
   output$CountryMap <- renderLeaflet({
   leaflet(Country) %>% addTiles() %>%
   fitBounds(Country$range[1], Country$range[3], Country$range[2], Country$range[4])%>%
   addPolygons(fillOpacity = 0.6,  smoothFactor = 0.5, stroke = TRUE, weight = 1)
})
}

shinyApp(ui =ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R Leaflet package does not have the option to disable `zoomControl` or `mouseWheelControl` yet according to this https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/179, but inspired by Yihui's suggestion from the link, here is a workaround that dynamically changes the `maxZoom` level depending on mouse click event.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(maps)

ui <- fluidPage(
    leafletOutput("CountryMap", width = 1000, height = 500)
)

server <- function(input, output){

    Country = map("world", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE, regions="USA", exact=TRUE)

    # Add a default minZoom and maxZoom of the same value so that the map does not zoom
    output$CountryMap <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(Country) %>% addTiles(options=tileOptions(minZoom=4, maxZoom=4)) %>%
            fitBounds(Country$range[1], Country$range[3], Country$range[2], Country$range[4]) %>%
            addPolygons(fillOpacity = 0.6,  smoothFactor = 0.5, stroke = TRUE, weight = 1)               
    })

    # Change a reactive value depending on mouse click
    zoom <- reactiveValues(level=4)

    # This records mouse clicks outside polygons
    observeEvent(input$CountryMap_click, {
        zoom$level = 20
    })

    # This records mouse clicks inside polygons
    observeEvent(input$CountryMap_shape_click, {
        zoom$level = 20
    })

    # Change zoom level of the map
    observe({
        if (zoom$level == 20) {
            leafletProxy("CountryMap") %>% clearTiles() %>%
                addTiles(options=tileOptions(minZoom=4, maxZoom=20))
        }
    })

}

shinyApp(ui =ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4):

I very much like the idea of **warmoverflow**, since it is purely on R side and very easy to understand. I only just saw that he has already answered your question. But since I already worked on another solution, I migth as well post it here. Doesn't hurt to have multiple options.

I produced a JavaScript solution that finds the leaflet `map` element and alters the `scrollWheelZoom` property. This would have been very straight forward, since you can just `disable` scroll zoom on start up and `enable` it as soon as the map has been clicked the first time. But the leaflet guys made things more difficult with [this fix to another issue](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/commit/ac1b64683a1bb9eae4bc11ff0e5910da4bf7123f). There, they (besides other things) added a listener, which `enables` scroll zoom, whenever the mouse moves (pretty annoying). So in my fix, we add a `script` to the document that also adds a listener to the mouse move event to `disable` (and thereby cancel the `enable` of) the `scrollWheelZoom` property. When the `map` is clicked on for the first time, this event listener will be removed, and thus you have normal (default) zoom options.

Code with Script below:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(maps)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("CountryMap", width = 1000, height = 500),
  tags$script("
    $(document).ready(function() {    
      setTimeout(function() {

        var map = $('#CountryMap').data('leaflet-map');            
        function disableZoom(e) {map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();}

        $(document).on('mousemove', '*', disableZoom);

        map.on('click', function() {
          $(document).off('mousemove', '*', disableZoom);
          map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
        });
      }, 100);
    })
  ")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  Country = map("world", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE, regions="USA", exact=TRUE)
  output$CountryMap <- renderLeaflet({
     leaflet(Country) %>% addTiles() %>%
     fitBounds(Country$range[1], Country$range[3], Country$range[2], Country$range[4])%>%
     addPolygons(fillOpacity = 0.6,  smoothFactor = 0.5, stroke = TRUE, weight = 1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui =ui, server = server)
```