# Interactive map for Latitude-Longitude based Sales data

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, maps

I have a data-frame with only 3 column viz latitude ,longitude and sales. These latitudes and longitudes belong to "Saudi Arabia" . I want to create interactive heatmap for sales based on Latitude and longitude.

Something like the "Zip-Explorer" example in shiny

```
 http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html
```

I tried experimenting with various examples

```
1. http://www.geo.ut.ee/aasa/LOOM02331/heatmap_in_R.html
```

This is not an interactive map,  hence In tried the  Shiny- leaflet example.

```
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881107/shiny-is-there-a-way-to-enable-mouse-wheel-zoom-only-after-click-on-map-in-shin?rq=1
```

In this case changing the region to USA to Saudi Arabia or SA doesn't help

```
 Country = map("world", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE, regions="USA", exact=TRUE)
```

**In the nutshell, I don't know how to go ahead with plotting Interactive Maps in R.**

Any suggestion will be helpful. Sample data-frame is given below.

```
data <- data.frame(latitude=c(37.78,24.77,21.56,24.77,21.56,21.56,21.47,21.48,26.39,24.77),longitude=c(-100,46.74,39.19,46.74,39.2,39.2,39.23,39.19,49.98,46.74),sales=c(830,128,120,73,41,37,35,31,29,28))
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet is great for this type of mapping and it is easy to scale up for this type of use case. With just latitude & longitude points its difficult to make a heatmap. For this example I just used circles that I colored with `colorFactor` to make it reflective of the value in `data$sales`:

```
library(leaflet)

data <- data.frame(latitude=c(37.78,24.77,21.56,24.77,21.56,21.56,21.47,21.48,26.39,24.77),
                   longitude=c(-100,46.74,39.19,46.74,39.2,39.2,39.23,39.19,49.98,46.74),
                   sales=c(830,128,120,73,41,37,35,31,29,28))

pal <- colorFactor(
  palette = 'Blues', domain = data$sales)

leaflet(data) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lat = ~latitude, lng = ~longitude, color= ~pal(sales))
```

yields a map of your data points, here is one area of focus:

[image]