# R Shiny leaflet stop zoom on scroll and use ctrl + scroll to zoom the map & move map with two fingers on mobile?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet

I am creating 100 + leaflet maps in my shiny app.
The maps are 100% of the width of the page, so when the user goes to scroll down the page it zooms the map but I would like it to continue scrolling down the page.

I've found this similar answer but I want the scrollWheelZoom to disabled all the time for every map.

Is there a way to change the Javascript to disable the scrollWheelZoom for all maps?

[Shiny: Is there a way to enable mouse wheel zoom only after click on map in shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881107/shiny-is-there-a-way-to-enable-mouse-wheel-zoom-only-after-click-on-map-in-shin)